# If a character teleports more than 2 squares while hidden, do they need to reroll stealth with a -5 penalty?

Tags: dnd-4e, stealth, teleportation

If a character teleports more than 2 squares while hidden, do they need to reroll stealth with a -5 penalty?

The rules for stealth specify:

> Keep Still: If the creature moves more than 2 squares during an action, it must make a Stealth check to remain hidden, with a -5 penalty, or a -10 penalty if the creature runs.

What if a player teleports (eg: an Eladrin rogue using fey step) and the new destination would otherwise be a good hiding location (eg: hiding behind a wall, then teleporting across an open room to another spot behind a wall); do they still have to roll with the -5 penalty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 'movement' is defined as leaving one square and entering another, our group has interpreted teleporting as moving one square. You left the square you were in, and entered the destination square, without moving from or into any squares in between. So we aren't applying the -5.

Personally, if I were the DM, and someone teleported to a good hiding spot, I might actually give them a situational bonus to their stealth check, since no one could have possibly seen them enter that square. That's just a house rule though.

From the Rules Compendium, pg 200:

move: ... Whenever a creature, an object, or an effect leaves a square to enter another, it is moving. ...

From the Rules Compendium, pg 213

Instantaneous: Teleportation takes no time. The target disappears and immediately reappears in the desination...

Answer (score 4):

RAW they do have to reroll stealth since they did move more than 2 squares. The character may never have passed the open room, but you can explain the -5 stealth check as noise associated with the teleport.